# Pandas Use Value if Not Null, Else Use Value From Next Column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': ['A', np.nan,'A'], 
                   'COL2' : [np.nan,'A','A']})
df
    COL1    COL2
0    A      NaN
1    NaN    A
2    A      A
```

I would like to create a column ('COL3') that uses the value from COL1 per row unless that value is null (or NaN). If the value is null (or NaN), I'd like for it to use the value from COL2.

The desired result is:

```
    COL1    COL2   COL3
0    A      NaN    A
1    NaN    A      A
2    A      A      A
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am working on similar kind of problem statement, but instead of column value I want to get column name. Can someone please help me on that? The output should be:-COL1 COL2 COL3
0    A  NaN    col1
1  NaN    B   col2
2    A    B    col1

Answer (score 102, accepted):

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
  COL1 COL2
0    A  NaN
1  NaN    B
2    A    B

In [9]: df["COL3"] = df["COL1"].fillna(df["COL2"])

In [10]: df
Out[10]:
  COL1 COL2 COL3
0    A  NaN    A
1  NaN    B    B
2    A    B    A
```

Comment: This is awesome! It can be chained and even works for dates with NaT or nan. A million upvotes needed.

Comment: This is brilliant!

Answer (score 11):

You can use `np.where` to conditionally set column values.

```
df = df.assign(COL3=np.where(df.COL1.isnull(), df.COL2, df.COL1))

>>> df
  COL1 COL2 COL3
0    A  NaN    A
1  NaN    A    A
2    A    A    A
```

If you don't mind mutating the values in COL2, you can update them directly to get your desired result.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': ['A', np.nan,'A'], 
                   'COL2' : [np.nan,'B','B']})

>>> df
  COL1 COL2
0    A  NaN
1  NaN    B
2    A    B

df.COL2.update(df.COL1)

>>> df
  COL1 COL2
0    A    A
1  NaN    B
2    A    A
```

Comment: I am working on similar kind of problem statement, but instead of column value I want to get column name. Can someone please help me on that? The output should be:-COL1 COL2 COL3
0    A  NaN    col1
1  NaN    B   col2
2    A    B    col1

Comment: This is the error I get, `SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
`

Answer (score 8):

Using `.combine_first`, which gives precedence to non-null values in the Series or DataFrame calling it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': ['A', np.nan,'A'], 
                   'COL2' : [np.nan,'B','B']})

df['COL3'] = df.COL1.combine_first(df.COL2)
```

Output:

```
  COL1 COL2 COL3
0    A  NaN    A
1  NaN    B    B
2    A    B    A
```

Answer (score 3):

If we mod your df slightly then you will see that this works and in fact will work for any number of columns so long as there is a single valid value:

```
In [5]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': ['B', np.nan,'B'], 
                   'COL2' : [np.nan,'A','A']})
df

Out[5]:
  COL1 COL2
0    B  NaN
1  NaN    A
2    B    A

In [6]:    
df.apply(lambda x: x[x.first_valid_index()], axis=1)

Out[6]:
0    B
1    A
2    B
dtype: object
```

[`first_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html) will return the index value (in this case column) that contains the first non-NaN value:

```
In [7]:
df.apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index(), axis=1)

Out[7]:
0    COL1
1    COL2
2    COL1
dtype: object
```

So we can use this to index into the series

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) which replaces the values where `COL1` is *NaN* by column `COL2`:

```
In [8]: df.assign(COL3=df['COL1'].mask(df['COL1'].isna(), df['COL2']))
Out[8]: 
  COL1 COL2 COL3
0    A  NaN    A
1  NaN    A    A
2    A    A    A
```